# Have a fixed DIV element with re-sizing constraints

Tags: css, html, layout, position

I have a website with the following basic layout. Essentially, I have the `NAV` div and `SIDEBAR` div at fixed positions. This is because when a user scrolls down on my page, only the `MIDDLE COLUMN` div will move.

The problem I have is that when the window gets shrunk horizontally, the SIDEBAR moves to left and eventually overlaps my `MIDDLE COLUMN`.

I have the `body` set to a `min-width` but it only affects the SIDEBAR if it is `position:absolute` and not `position:fixed`

Is there a way to keep my same method of scrolling, but have the `SIDEBAR` div stop moving left after a certain pixel constraint?

Thanks!

EDIT MARKUP:

```
div.MASTER {
    position: inherit;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

div.NAV {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:200px;
}

div.CONTENT {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
}

div.MIDDLECOLUMN {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

div.SIDEBAR {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width:200px;
}
```

[image: Diagram]

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Comment: @Ray I added the CSS markup for all of the following divs. My body div has `min-width:900px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I see the issue. You need to assign a min width on the main container. Set the min-width to the width of the element right before it breaks.

Add a margin-left equal to the width of the nav bar to the content div.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I made a mistake on my markup, the SIDEBAR has `position:fixed` and changing the min-width didn't seem to work. It seems when a div has a fixed position, it will ignore all min-width contraints

Comment: Thanks that seemed to do the trick!

As a side note, I have the content div as `width:100%` so it can be centered horizontally when the browser is resized. Now that I have that margin, using a percentage width inbetween two blocks with pixel widths makes it operate weird. I can use a relative percent but it will look different based on resolution, correct?

Anyway around this?

Comment: are you using breakpoints? I recommend setting a relative percentage width to each container with min / max widths and adjusting with breakpoints. Another method would to use jquery to calculate the width on resize

Comment: I wasn't using breakpoints but setting the min-widths seemed to do the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scroll function in jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var $left= $('#yourdiv').offset().left + 20; //+20 is optional

$(window).scroll(function()
{   
 if ($(window).scrollLeft()>$left)   
        {
         $('#yourdiv').addClass('floater');
         $('#yourdiv').removeClass('floated')
        }
        else
        {
         $('#yourdiv').removeClass('floater');
         $('#yourdiv').addClass('floated')

         }
});
});
```

where floater class is with posit absolute and floated is with position fixed.

EDIT 1:

Maybe you can use all percentage width even in the NAV bar like:

```
.nav{width:20%; position:fixed;} 

.master{width:60%; position:absolute;margin-left:21%; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did try that, but the problem is that when the SIDEBAR becomes `position:absolute`, it will scroll with the rest of the page.